# About left-orderable group and convex subgroup

Tags: group-theory, order-theory

Let  $G= \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<a,b,c,d \mid \text{finite number of defining relations}>$  be  a left-orderable group.
Let $H=\<a,b \mid \text{a partial subset  of defining relations of $G$}>$ a convex subgroup of $G$ relative to some left-order $<$.
Then $G$ acts by orientation preserving homeomorphisms on the real line (as it is countable).

Is it necessarily true that:

1. $H$ admits a fixed point $x \in \mathbf R$
2. the subgroup generated by $c$, $d$ (with another partial subset of defining relations of $G$) acts freely on this $x$?

I would appreciate very much if you could also refer me to the
relevant literature.

Comment: I do not think that everybody knows the notion of left-orderable group. Maybe you could at least add a [link to Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_ordered_group). Or explain the definition, if your definition is different from Wikipedia.

Comment: On the other hand, somebody who doesn't know the definition of a left-orderable group is very unlikely to be able to help answer the question!

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer is negative, but you are most probably referring to the action produced by the order (the so-called dynamical realization). In that case, the answer for 1. is YES. For 2. it is not true: consider for instance a lexicographic order on Z^4. What is true is that the action on this fixed point has neither lower nor upper limit. More information is in http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5805

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have looked at this paper several times (it is very well-written), but I didn't find the answer to my questions. Where can I find the proof of  the positive answer of 1 , or at least the idea behind it? Concerning qn2, are there classical/well-known examples of left-orderable groups that act freely on the reals (by orientation-preserving homeomorphisms) ?